# How can I constrain T to support DataContractJsonSerializer, and not implement ISerializable everywhere?

Tags: c#, json, generics, serialization, extension-methods

I'm working on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771582/optimized-json-serialiser-deserialiser-as-an-extension-method) extension method and am trying to constrain T so that the method doesn't apply to EVERY object... just the ones that the DataContractJsonSerializer works well with

```
public static string ToJSONString(this object obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

            ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: "works well with"?  Need to be more specific.  The DataContractJsonSerializer doesn't apply only to objects that implement a specific interface.  It applies to everybody.

Comment: Aren't there some object that don't work with `DataContractJsonSerializer`?  I just want to exclude them.  For example, `System.Console` should be excluded... unless you're saying it can be serialized?

Comment: There's nothing the code would know about that would say "Console cannot be serialized".  DataContractJsonSerializer  doesn't look for any interface.  It just accepts an object.  Whether that serialization succeeds or fails, it won't know until it tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options available inside generics are... Limited. One workaround is to use reflection (typically in a static ctor on a generic type) to check with reflection, but tbh this may be overkill. Could you perhaps add `where T : class, new()` which may go a long way to limit it to "entity"/DTO types.